# How to configure Credentials for VertexAi java Chat Language Model

Tags: java, environment-variables, langchain, google-cloud-vertex-ai, large-language-model

I am trying to create a VertexAi Java Chat Language Model object to generate Chat responses for a Java Application

The VertexAiChatModel class accepts the below parameters

```
ChatLanguageModel chatModel = VertexAiChatModel.builder()
                .endpoint(llm_endpoint)
                .project(project_name)
                .location(region)
                .publisher("google")
                .modelName("text-bison@001")
                .temperature(0.7)
                .maxOutputTokens(1024)
                .topK(40)
                .topP(0.95)
                .maxRetries(3)
                .build();
```

The "generate" method of this object does not work while running from IDE since the credentials have not been authenticated.
However, I am able to run it from the GCP Console since I am logged in.

I have the credentials(type,project Id, private_key_id, private_key) in a JSON file

I am not sure how to input this JSON file to the Chat Model object, or whether it has to be added to environment. Also, no documentation was found on the Credential Configuration for VertexAi.

Similar Chat Model class for OpenAi does not have issue since it accepts the API key as a parameter

```
            ChatLanguageModel chatModel= OpenAiChatModel.builder()
                    .apiKey(apiKey.getInsecureString())
                    .timeout(Duration.ofSeconds(queryTimeout.intValue()))
                    .maxTokens(maxTokens.intValue())
                    .temperature(temperature)
                    .maxRetries(null)
                    .build();
```

Please let me know how I can authenticate my ChatLanguageModel object with the JSON credentials file.

Comment: Hi @Sachu, Have you checked this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/provide-credentials-adc) to Set up Application Default Credentials, also have a look at this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/generative-ai/start/quickstarts/quickstart-chat#aiplatform_sdk_chat-java) and let me know  if this helps you or not ?

Comment: Sure @DhirajSingh Will check and let you know.

Comment: @Sachu I recently [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77738985/10347145) a similar question. See the *Google Vertex AI SDK* part. Also, I've made a [YouTube tutorial](https://youtu.be/I8W-4oq1onY) on how to use the Vertex AI Gemini Pro API, where I also covered this step of setting the ADC, and posted the [code](https://github.com/rokbenko/google-ai-api-tutorials/tree/main/Tutorials/2%20Vertex%20AI%20Gemini%20Pro%20API%20starter) on my GitHub profile.

Comment: Thank you @RokBenko. I saw the answer. I will try setting the environment variable and confirm.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Gemini API error: "DefaultCredentialsError: Your default credentials were not found."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77727695/google-gemini-api-error-defaultcredentialserror-your-default-credentials-were)

Comment: @DhirajSingh sorry your answer did not solve my problem. I still am not able to run the Java function with authentication. I don't want to use cli since it is for application integration. I should be able to get it from service account credentials without environment setup.

Answer (score 1):

You can provide either your user credentials or service account credentials to ADC in a local development environment  as mentioned in this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/provide-credentials-adc).

When your code is running in a local development environment, such as a development workstation, the best option is to use credentials associated with your Google Account, also called [user credentials](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/provide-credentials-adc#local-user-cred). You can set up ADC with credentials from a service account by using service account impersonation or by using a [service account key](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/provide-credentials-adc#local-key). The detailed steps are mentioned in the above documentations.

As commented by @Rok Benko, you can refer to this similar [stack answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77738985/10347145) for more inputs.